# CSS styling not symmetrical in different size window

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I made a simple page that looks like below:

[image]

It looks fine but if I change it to a smaller window or changing the zoom %, this is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, it's not right as the button is way off but the `<p>` and `<h>` tag seems to be align but not the button.

Here is my relevant part of the code:

```
function Pitch() {
  return (
    <div className="section">
      <div className="descriptionpitch">
        <h1>See what's next.</h1>
        <p>WATCH ANYWHERE. CANCEL ANYTIME.</p>
      </div>
      <div className="joinbutton">
        <button>JOIN FREE FOR A MONTH</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

scss:

```
.section {
  color: white;
  margin: 0 3%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  //text-align: center;

  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    top: 55%;
    font-size: 1.9vw;
  }
  @media (max-width: 800px) {
    top: 60%;
    font-size: 3.2vw;
    margin: 0 4em;
    text-align: center;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0 0 0.2em;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  p {
    margin: 0 3.5em 0 0;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  button {
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1.9px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 1.2em 24.5em 0 0;
    padding: 12px 2em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #e50914;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    //vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
    user-select: none;
    // text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    &:hover {
      background-color: #e53935;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way i could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..add this in same div.. if u want more space at the top of the button. add margin-top for this button

```
function Pitch() {
  return (
    <div className="section">
      <div className="descriptionpitch">
        <h1>See what's next.</h1>
        <p>WATCH ANYWHERE. CANCEL ANYTIME.</p>
        <button>JOIN FREE FOR A MONTH</button>
      </div>      
    </div>
  );
}
```

And modify this css code too..

**css**

```
  @media (max-width: 800px) {
    .section {
        text-align: left;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It just moves the button away from the text, doesn't align it together

Comment: wait why did you declare `descriptionpitch`?

Comment: I just modified ur code that's it.. i add the all the texts in the same div

Comment: Okay it does work now but if i enlarge my browser again to full size, the red button becomes out of alignment again lol

Comment: I want to make sure it's always symmetric regardless of the window size.

Comment: I've been spending hours on this and this is so frustracting lol.

Comment: Okay i think it works, can you also help me with a different one similar to this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199106/discussion-between-daredevil-and-manikandan2811).

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code, make on change, remove `text-align: center;` from this block

```
...
  @media (max-width: 800px) {
    top: 60%;
    font-size: 3.2vw;
    margin: 0 4em;
    /* text-align: center; */
  }
...
```

working [demo on stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wz5l41)

Comment: did you check in the stackblitz that I shared?

Comment: yes, within the `@media (max-width: 800px) ` only... commented it out to help see it and you can see the rendered output in real-time also

Comment: Do you mean that the result of stackblitz is same as the previous erroneous state?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin-right from the button in your 800px media query.